# Is it possible to configure different write timeouts per Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, configuration, datastax-enterprise

I have a datastax cassandra cluster with 8 nodes. The keyspace used by the application contains about 400 Tables. The parameter `write_request_timeout_in_ms` in the `cassandra.yaml` is set to `2000ms` (default).

The default value is high enough for most tables. However, I for only two tables I require a much higher write_request_timeout. I know that stuff such as bloomfilter false-positive chance or compaction strategy can be configured per table.

Is that possible to do the same for timeouts and if so then how?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to configure different write timeouts because all writes are persisted to the same `commitlog` disk.

A coordinator will return a write timeout if not enough replicas (based on the write consistency level) acknowledged the write (to the `commitlog` disk) because the disk is busy.

Since there is only one `commitlog` disk on each node, it makes no sense to have different write timeouts. This in fact raises another question -- what problem are you trying to solve?

Increasing timeouts is almost never the right thing to do since all it does is hide the problem. You need to identify the root of the issue and fix it. Cheers!